# Optimize: split pandas DataFrame with DatetimeIndex based on date into list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two `DataFrames` with `DatetimeIndex`: `train_df` of dimensions `[981240 rows x 12 columns]` and `eval_df` of dimensions `[98670 rows x 12 columns]`.

I am trying to split each `DataFrame` into a `list` of `DataFrame`s where each represents a unique `date` (contains the slice of the indices with the respective `date`).

My current code:

```
train_data = [train_df.loc[train_df.index.date == date][nan_rows:].copy().dropna() for date in np.unique(train_df.index.date)]
eval_data = [eval_df.loc[eval_df.index.date == date][nan_rows:].copy().dropna() for date in np.unique(eval_df.index.date)]
```

This takes far too long to complete. I was wondering if anybody knows how to optimize this operation to complete in a reasonable amount of time?

By the way, `nan_rows` is just number of rows I would like to remove from the top of each `DataFrame` in the list.

Comment: maybe `groupby` on date or sort the index and then split at locations where diff != 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
# assuming that your datetime column is called 'Datetime'
train_data = [x for x in train_df.set_index('Datetime').groupby(lambda x: x.date, axis=0)]
eval_data = [x for x in eval_df.set_index('Datetime').groupby(lambda x: x.date, axis=0)]
```

Comment: This brought a tear to my eye when I saw how quickly it executed. Thank you.